# Given 'n' number of unique positive integers, how many unique sum values can I make?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have three integer values

```
[1,2,3]
```

With above three values, I can form total 8 values ($2^3$).

```
 0                        (Pick 0 value)
 1, 2, 3,                 (Pick only 1 value)
 3[1+2], 4[1+3], 5[2+3],  (Pick 2 values)
 6[1+2+3]                 (Pick 3 values)
```

However, Notice how there are duplicate outcomes.
`3` and `3[1+2]` ?

So I would say that using three numbers `1,2,3`, I can form total 7 unique numbers.

But is there any formula I can apply to find out the cardinality of only the unique outcomes ?

Some more example set of numbers to consider.

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,3,5,7]
```

Comment: The example sets contain non-unique numbers. Is it intentional or mistakenly typed?

Comment: The examples suggest you actually have multisets? Like from $[1,2,2,3]$ we could sum $2+2+3=7$ but not $2+2+2$ or $2+3+3$?

Comment: @user79161 Yes, non-unique numbers are there intentionally. I thought that a set with unique numbers are easier to think about. That is why I started with set of unique integer values. However, I realized that now I am asking two different questions by introducing a set with non-unique elements. I will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: For the case $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$ unique outcomes (see [OEIS A000124](https://oeis.org/A000124)).

Comment: And for the case $[n]=\{1,2,4,\ldots,2^{n-1}\}$, there are $2^n$ unique outcomes.

Comment: @BillyJoe, it might be interesting to know, if $N$ is a number between ${n(n+1)\over2}+1$ and $2^n$, is there a set of $n$ positive integers for which the cardinality of the set of unique sum values is equal to $N$? (Admittedly I haven't given this much thought; the answer might be trivial.)

Answer (score 0):

In the following list I wrote $(n,values)$ where $n$ is the number of different elements in the set and $values$ is the number of different values we can get taking $0$ elements, $1$ element, $2$ element, and so on.
$$(0,1),(1,2),(2,4),(3,7),(4,11),(5,16),(6,22),\ldots$$
$$values=\frac{1}{2} \left(n^2+n+2\right)$$
Hope this can help

---

Edit

Only works for lists of consecutive integers, like $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$

Comment: This isn't always valid. Take for example $\{1,3,5\}$: the unique outcomes are $0,1,3,5,4,6,8,9$ so a total of $8$. Your formula is valid for $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: @BillyJoe You are right! Thank you for pointing it out. So a general formula must be much more complex